# Get resulting ID after an insert

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

Suppose I have the following table:

```
 public class SomeItem
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
 }
```

I can easily do something like:

```
var items = await MobileService.GetTable<SomeItem>.Where(x=>x.Id > 50).ToListAsync();
//print items here
```

but I haven't been able to find a way to get the resulting item once it has been inserted. For example, I may need the Id from `SomeItem`. This is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
var item = await MobileService.GetTable<SomeItem>.Insert(new SomeItem{Text="hi"}).Result;
```

Comment: Why not just do `var newItem = new SomeItem{Text="hi"}` and then insert `newItem`? Then you have `newItem` available right there!

Comment: @MatthewWatson will the newItem populate with the Id (key) that the DB automatically creates?

Comment: No it won't - I'd thought you were setting the Id yourself but of course, I can see you are not.

Comment: I actually just tested it and it, indeed, does update the Id of the item. If you wish to "answer", it has met my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create the item that you want to insert separately, so that you have a reference to it that you can use after the insert:

```
var newItem = new SomeItem{Text="hi"};
await MobileService.GetTable<SomeItem>.Insert(newItem); // Or whatever syntax you need here!
// Now you can use newItem after it's been inserted (and the 'Id' key has been updated by the insert)
```

Comment: (Don't tell anyone... but so was I ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are breaking changes to this in the (currently) beta client SDK.  See this post on the details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/03/14/azure-mobile-services-managed-client-upcoming-breaking-changes.aspx

In the code you supplied in the answer, since "SomeItem" is a known data-type, I think the behavior will be unchanged and the object will be patched in place.  If you are using un-typed data(JSON), the object will NOT be patched in place.  You'd have to rely on the returned object to inspect the value of the id.  Carlos explains that very point in better detail in the post above.

Nate